# Why are my quotation marks being ignored in my shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, freebsd

I'm trying to write an install shell script in /bin/sh in FreeBSD.

> DialogOptions='--trim --ok-label "Next" --backtitle "Workstation Installer"'
>
> dialog $DialogOptions --max-input 4 --cancel-label "Abort" --inputbox "Enter stuff"

The above exits with the error

> Error: Unknown option Installer.

I think when I pass the DialogOptions variable to the dialog it interprets the quotation marks differently. I'm at a loss as to why it would.

I've also noticed that the ok label shows "Next" instead of Next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to use an array, which will keep your quoted arguments un-split:

```
DialogOptions=(--trim --ok-label "Next" --backtitle "Workstation Installer")
dialog "${DialogOptions[@]}" --max-input 4 --cancel-label "Abort" --inputbox "Enter stuff"
```

You also need to use a shell that supports arrays: bash/ksh/zsh. Failing that, you have to use `eval`:

```
DialogOptions='--trim --ok-label Next --backtitle "Workstation Installer"'
eval "dialog $DialogOptions --max-input 4 --cancel-label Abort --inputbox \"Enter stuff\""
```

Note that you don't *have* to quote strings that don't contain any characters in `$IFS`

Comment: sadly I can't use a different shell so no arrays. Happily your eval solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the *shell* is concerned, it should be behaving exactly as you expect:

```
$ DialogOptions='--trim --ok-label "Next" --backtitle "Workstation Installer"'
```

At this point, the variable "DialogOptions" contains a single string

```
$ echo ..$DialogOptions..
..--trim --ok-label "Next" --backtitle "Workstation Installer"..
```

The echo command sees *five* arguments: --trim, --ok-label, "Next" --backtitle and "Workstation Installer"

Comment: Incorrect: after the shell has completed it's expansions, including word splitting, echo sees **six** arguments: `..--trim`, `-ok-label`, `Next`, `--backtitle`, `"Workstation`, and `Installer"..`